# Synchronize Couchdb with Front-End

Tags: html, node.js, apache, nosql, couchdb

I just wonder if there cloud that include couchdb and html, css, js together?
What is the relevant option to synchronize html, js, css with couchdb without to use 2 hosts..

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's very simple:
Every Document can contain ATTACHMENTS based on html, js, css etc...